# Using MySQL ANTLR4 grammar in C#, getting "The type or namespace name 'MySQLBaseLexer' could not be found"

Tags: c#, mysql, parsing, antlr4, grammar

I am trying to play around with the ANTLR4 grammars for MySQL to do some basic statement parsing.  This is my first time using ANTLR.  I created a blank C# console project in VS2017, installed the ANTLR4, ANTLR4.CodeGenerator and Antlr4.Runtime nuget packages as well as the ANTLR Language Support extension.  I added in the MySQLLexer.g4, MySQLParser.g4 and the predefined.tokens file.  When I try to build the solution I get the following error:

`The type or namespace name 'MySQLBaseLexer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"`

I have been looking through the tutorials, SO, and other blogs that discuss using ANTLR4 on C# but nothing seems to resolve the errors.  Could anyone point me in the right direction to get this working correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using the two grammar files [located here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/tree/8.0/library/parsers/grammars). While those grammars may not contain C++ code, it requires the base class you mention which is C++ code, so you will need to port `MySQLBaseLexer.cpp` and auxiliary code to C#, which is found in the Git repo. The [readme in the ANTLR4 grammar directory](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/mysql/Oracle) contains a few more details about this requirement.

Also, why don't you try using Visual Studio 2019, the official Java Antlr Tool 4.7.2 (which requires Java), and my Net Core template for generating an Antlr C# program? Everything is integrated into a build and run F5. Check out [this](https://github.com/kaby76/Antlr4BuildTasks/tree/master/Templates) and [this](https://github.com/kaby76/Antlr4BuildTasks). The C# tool is at least two years behind the official release of Antlr. Further, the *.tokens is a generated file.

I don't understand why people keep checking in Antlr-generated files into a repo. It should not be checked in and used, especially if you use my template. The .g4 files are your source. If you need an extension for editing Antlr grammars in VS, you might want to check out my AntlrVSIX extension.

Comment: Thanks for your response @kaby76!  I tried your suggestion using VS2019, the .NET Core template and Java Antlr Tool 4.7.2.  I already had Java installed and I verified the installation using the instructions on the page and got the expected output.  However, when I create a new project using the template it still gives me the same "Type or namespace could not be found".  It specifies a different namespace since it is referencing the arithmeticLexer and arithmeticParser classes.  I verified my versions all match as well.  Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?  Thanks...

Comment: In your new project, right-click on the .g4 files in the Solution Manager, and open up the Properties. Make sure to set "Build Action" to "ANTLR 4 grammar". Also, set the "Custom Tool Namespace" to what you are using for your project (that is, the Antlr Tool will generate a parser in a namespace you give). Then, try a clean and then rebuild.

Comment: There're good reasons to keep the generated parser/lexer files in a repo: 1) especially for non-Java languages this makes building the app simpler (no Java required then), 2) you can better track changes in the generated files, resulting from grammar changes. Enough reasons for me to keep those files in the Workbench repo.

Comment: After going through and correcting the "Custom Tool Namespace" it cleared up a bunch of errors, but there is still one remaining.  

```'CommonTokenStream' does not contain a definition for 'OutputTokens' and the best extension method overload 'Output.OutputTokens(IList<IToken>)' requires a receiver of type 'IList<IToken>'```

Any thoughts on how to resolve that one?

Comment: You could save the .cs/.tokens files from a parser generate, but with Antlr4BuildTasks, these files are output to the obj/ directory, just like .obj's. It's likely Harwell's C# code generator does the same--I forked Antlr4BuildTasks from his code, and replaced the C# code generator with a Java Antlr Tool call. Saving the files decouples the build dependency on Java.exe, but you should then remove the dependency on Antlr4BuildTasks so as to not have two versions of the parser being compiled into your program. For OutputTokens, make sure to pass the CommonTokeStream, not the AntlrInputStream.

Comment: I checked the .cs and .tokens files and none of them have references to CommonTokenStream or OutputTokens except for an extension method in the Output.cs file that is created when the template is used.  I posted the files from my test project on pastebin.  [link](https://pastebin.com/NNp2x9R3) [link](https://pastebin.com/71qk2F8Q) [link](https://pastebin.com/w2Unmjfy) [link](https://pastebin.com/5bQiwdQa) [link](https://pastebin.com/mK4JExp0)

Comment: Looks fine. At https://github.com/kaby76/Antlr4BuildTasks/blob/master/Foo.zip is a zip file with your code, a csproj file, a git bash script and 'out' file of running the script. Run git bash on the script or type it out in your favorite command-line shell, and compare with the file 'out'. That should get you started. It seems the template isn't working out of the box.

Comment: That may be the difference.  I didn't use the 'dotnet' commands to create the project.  I used VS2019 and created a new project using the 'AntlrCAProject' template.  Maybe there's something that VS2019 isn't doing when it creates the project using the template?  I did notice that when I use this process via VS2019 it uses the 1.0.8 version of the Antlr4BuildTasks instead of the 1.0.9 version that it uses when doing it via the shell.  I am not sure if that is what is causing the issue though because even when I update it to 1.0.9, clean and build in VS2019 it still fails.

Comment: Are you using the Antlrvsix extension for Visual Studio 2017/9? That has some older templates in the extension, but I guess has problems. I'm still working out an LSP client/server implementation for Antlr and haven't updated Antlrvsix for a while.

Comment: Yes, I see now. Thank you for the note. The Antlrvsix template is just wrong. So sorry! The Antlrvsix extension has templates currently in it. I'm planning on removing all the templates from the extension itself, and have Antlr4BuildTasks.Templates contain all the templates from now on. So, use "dotnet new ..." from now on. But, it'll likely be a few weeks before I'm done with the extension---I'm stuck on the LSP implementation at the moment.

Comment: I continued using the dotnet commands to create the project.  After creating it I added the MySQLParser.g4 and MySQLLexer.g4 files.  I verified that the Build Action, Custom Tool and Custom Tool Name were set and did a build.  I am again getting the ```the type or namespace name 'MySQLBaseLexer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)``` in the MySQLLexer.cs file that is auto generated.  I get a similar error for the MySQLBaseRecognizer in the MySQLParser.cs file.  It also cannot find the tokens file 'predefined.tokens'.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You are going to need to port the C++ classes to C# used in the grammars (git clone --branch 8.0 https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench.git; cd mysql-workbench/library/parsers/mysql). Here (https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples) you can find a project with the grammars and some stub classes and interface to get you started. It doesn't build due to unported code from C++. I did notice that a predefined tokens file is used for ordering token types, but I commented it out. I would instead create a map of token type to ordinal to create the order. Use VS2019 at this point.

Comment: As I am writing a complete forward and reverse engineering transformation system for C++ to C#, I decided to try to port a little of the code, at least by hand to discover more of the things I need to look out for, as it would only take me a couple hours of work. There were a number of things C# can't handle--multiple inheritance (MySQLRecognizerCommon, Lexer/Parser); "enum class"; switch case fall thru that also contains a case handler; int/size_t/uint/enum mix ups; scopes of enums; Antlr runtime differences. Anyways, the code is at https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/tree/master/mysql

Comment: Instead of porting the code to C# could I compile the C++ and then call the C++ from C#?  I am not an experienced C++ coder, so porting that code would be pretty problematic and error prone.  Also, could you give me an example of how to create the map of type to ordinal?  Thanks!

Comment: You could try that but I haven't tested the target option for the extension for C++. For the map, I haven't looked further at it. But in C#, it is a Dictionary<int,int>, where the key is token type and the second the token type defined in the predefined tokens file. I would just look for where token types are compared, and understand why it's ordered, then decide whether to extend the extension or use the map. I don't think there's much to do to get it executing though in C#, except then the need to test it. I plan to work on it today, as it's a good example.

Comment: I've now got it parsing "select * from foobar;". I will continue to refine and understand the code as there is rather complicate with the semantic predicates in the lexer. Generally speaking, porting is an opportunity to scrub existing code.

Comment: Much of the parser works, but there's a bug in lexing of "select 2 as expected, /*!01000/**/*/ 2 as result". It fails in ('/*!' DIGITS) {....}, C# runtime Lexer Text is wrong. I can't tell yet where's the problem until I debug simultaneously both C# and C++ and compare, esp. with nested comment (mysql doesn't allow, I read). All good stuff. Anyways, I think this StackOverflow question is complete. --Ken

Answer (score 0):

I was interested on this topic once I saw this topic, but went on vacations recently and I could finish the sample.

Here is a sample:
https://github.com/hmadrigal/playground-dotnet/tree/master/MsDotNetCore.MySqlParser

I created where the grammar provided by workbench (https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/tree/8.0/library/parsers/grammars) has been adapted to work on .NET Core (using .NET standard for portability)

**I created this sample project, it is not meant for production, and I am not an ANTLR expert, but I love coding and parsers.**

Take a look at README.md and https://github.com/hmadrigal/playground-dotnet/blob/master/MsDotNetCore.MySqlParser/MySqlParser.TerminalApp/MySqlParserTester.cs could be your bootstrap. If I ever get to write a blog post I'll share the notes in here.

Comment: Nice. FYI, the bad method name generated by Antlr, which you mention in the readme, is a bug in version 4.7.1 of Antlr. That was fixed in Antlr 4.7.2, but the latest version is now 4.8. The <target> rule and build-parsers.cmd file you use in the .csproj file is more generally handled using Antlr4BuildTasks via NuGet with a <PackageReference>. That tool works with Net Core, Framework, and believe or not VC++ projects--not an easy feat.

Comment: @kaby thanks for you insights. I updated the Antlr and everything worked as you have said.  At this time, I'll keep the custom msbuild task, but of course it can be replaced with the Antlr4BuildTasks.